# AutoMapper and loosly coupled tables

Tags: automapper, loose-coupling

Imagine this scenario.

- I store documents references and paths in a table.
- Multiple different entities and store documents in this table
- This table has no foreign keys except for DocumentType
- Documents are identified by the SourceType and SourceId columns e.g. SourceType = "People", SourceId = 1 or SourceType = "Company", SourceId = 23 etc. etc.

My question is how do I map from People to Document to DocumentType in order to get a list of all document types associated with a person?

[image]

Comment: Write the code with LINQ and _after_ that you can consider whether AM can help.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu That's not very helpful!

Comment: I think you need try to understand a little better how both LINQ and AM work and what kind of problems solve. There are plenty of docs and examples for both.